# How to make a trident reach further underwater in Java Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for ways to make a trident reach farther underwater in Java Minecraft. Currently, I think the grind was way too hard to get a very mediocre underwater boost, compared to just swimming with depth strider 3. Additionally, as a weapon, a sword is just infinitely better due to knockback and looting. Instead, the enchantment seems more like it's only intended to launch you out of water. So far, I've come up with 2 ideas:

1. Spawn in a trident with a higher-than-allowed level of riptide. This works, but has the drawback of launching you much higher out of water too, becoming lethal if you aim wrong.
2. Give players holding a riptide 3 trident dolphin's grace. The low friction effect is precisely what I'm looking for, but it's still faster to just use the dolphin's grace speed boost to swim when combined with depth stider.

Ideally, the effect only applies when launching yourself, not also when just holding the trident, but right-click detection methods are a bit too hacky for me, I prefer to keep it simple. I would optimally remove the speed boost effect from dolphin's grace and keep the friction reduction.

I'm currently using a self-made datapack implementing the second idea, but it's far too overpowered. I now have to remove my depth strider boots before going swimming. Is there any better way to achieve the intended behaviour, potentially with a plugin rather than a datapack? Perhaps it would be possible to lower the water friction though other means than dolphin's grace?

Comment: I don't think a data pack can do this. Mods can though. Maybe equip the player with depth strider when the trident is equipped.

Comment: I'm running a PaperMC server and am familiar with Java programming, so I could probably make a plugin as well, but this makes depth stider boots redundant. I would like for them to still have an effect when just swimming with the trident, I just want it to boost further underwater, similar to how it does with dolphin's grace, but without dolphin's grace applying to the swimming as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, turns out, [an old Minecraft bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-136249) is the source of my misery. I can't even vote for it to be fixed because the bug tracker's account creation is apperently disabled, with Reddit users reporting this is because of a bug with the bug tracker... Gotta be kidding me.

If you enter swimming mode without depth strider boots equipped, riptide tridents boost you much further, which seems to be the intended behaviour, as the bug entry is marked as open. You'd expect depth strider to boost trident reach, or at least leave it untouched.

There is apparently a client-side mod that fixes this problem, but it requires a modded client, whereas I prefer to play vanilla. Rather disappointed Mojang has failed to fix their, in my opinion, completely broken riptide mechanic since 1.13, but for now, I guess I'll hope they hurry up.

As for the mod ideas, modifying friction cannot be done using either datapacks or plugins. Perhaps a forge or fabric server/client could implement this, but I'm not planning to look into that. Dolphin's grace is the closest I got to the intended behaviour, but the resulting swim speed boost makes using the trident for boosting obsolete, and is generally too overpowered.